# Loading a page with a url that "automatically" clicks on a Javascript button, many times

Tags: javascript, url, web-scraping, load

I'm trying to load this website : [Staking Rewards](https://www.stakingrewards.com/assets) with the complete list loaded.

But this requires to click on a Javascript button "Load More".

Is it possible to have an URL like :

```
https://www.stakingrewards.com/assets?document.querySelector("#assets > main > div > section > section:nth-child(3) > section:nth-child(4) > button").click()
```

And do that many times (3 times) in the URL?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not possible. You could do this in Python however, upon page load, you could keep clicking the "load more" button until there were no more instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something like that with a bare-bones standard web browser. But if you installed a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/), you can write scripts to automatically execute when you visit a page.

The following script will click that button 3 times whenever you visit the page:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Staking Rewards Load More
// @include          https://www.stakingrewards.com/assets
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

let clicks = 0;
const intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
  const btn = document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Load More"]');
  if (btn) {
    btn.click();
    clicks++;
    if (clicks === 3) {
      window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```